# Lookup using INDEX and MATCH with two criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, lookup, excel-match

I am trying to achieve a basic lookup using INDEX and MATCH. My layout is:

```
Sheet 1
NAME | SITE | DATE

Sheet 2
NAME | SITE | DATE
```

I want the 'SITE' column in Sheet 1 to automatically populate with the SITE from Sheet 2 where NAME and DATE match.

**What I've Tried**

```
=INDEX('Sheet2'!B:B,MATCH(A1,'Sheet2'!A:A,0))
```

This will successfully match NAME, but how can I incorporate an additional MATCH into the formula to match on *both* NAME *and* DATE?

Comment: Concatenate the name and date together (into a helper column or something like that). Then you can use vlookup or index/match or whatever you want on the helper column to make sure that both the name and dates match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest the conventional solution to problems of this kind is to concatenate the pair of search terms (ie a helper column) and to add the concatenated pairs to the lookup array.

[image: SO18767439 example]

In the example above the concatenation of what to look up (rather than where to look up) is done 'on the fly'.

Comment: after fighting with the solution by @barry houdini, I finally gave up and used a helper column as you suggested.

Answer (score 13):

You can use an "array formula" like this

`=INDEX('Sheet2'!B:B,MATCH(1,(A1='Sheet2'!A:A)*(C1='Sheet2'!C:C),0))`

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

....or you can add another INDEX function so that it doesn't need to be "array entered", i.e.

`=INDEX('Sheet2'!B:B,MATCH(1,INDEX((A1='Sheet2'!A:A)*(C1='Sheet2'!C:C),0),0))`

or another way is to use LOOKUP like this

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(A1='Sheet2'!A:A)/(C1='Sheet2'!C:C),'Sheet2'!B:B)`

That latter method would give you the **last** match if there is more than one......

Comment: This seems like a correct solution, but after fighting for hours with this, I finally gave up (excel crashing all the time, maybe because of the amount of rows it needs to index?).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution without using an array and without using a helper column:

```
<i>=INDEX(Table[returnColumnName], 
MATCH(1, INDEX((Table[lookupColumn1] = "arraysAreSlow") * 
(Table[lookupColumn2] = "avoidWherePossible"), 0, 1), 0))</i>
```

Here is a more advanced solution that performs a grid lookup:

```
<i>=INDEX(Table,
MATCH(1, INDEX((Table[lookupColumn1] = "arraysAreSlow") * 
(Table[lookupColumn2] = "avoidWherePossible"), 0, 1), 0),
MATCH("returnColumnName", Table[#Headers],0))</i>
```