# VBA Search both values in row and return a different column value

Tags: vba, search, double

I have an excel sheet table with the following data:

[image]

In VBA how to search and match for both values in columns A and B and return row value in column C.
Example:
I need to search for the exact match of c+c1 and have as result yy

Many thanks for the help

Comment: Result as yy means what?  There are  no row numbers showing either in sample. What have you tried? Did you mean to return x5?   https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lookup using INDEX and MATCH with two criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767439/lookup-using-index-and-match-with-two-criteria)

Comment: @QHarr you're right. I made a mistake. The final result should be X5

Answer (score 0):

Use If statements when you loop through the rows like so:

```
If ws.cells(i,1).Value = c And ws.cells(i,2).value = c1 Then

result = yy
End If
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

U can create a 4th column, this column will be your key column to use in VBA. In this column you will concatenate the A and B values, after that we create a code that search the concat and return the 4th cell on the right.

[image: table]
.

```
Sub Example()

Dim keyRange As Range
Set keyRange = Planilha1.Range("A2:A8")

Dim SearchValue1, SearchValue2 As String

SearchValue1 = "a"
SearchValue2 = "a2"

Dim lin As Integer
lin = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(SearchValue1 & SearchValue2, keyRange, 0)

Dim answer As String
answer = Planilha1.Range("A2:D8").Cells(lin, 4)

Debug.Print answer


End Sub
```